# Why is branchless Heapsort 1.5x faster than with branching?

Tags: performance, assembly, rust, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I know about CPU branch misprediction penalty, etc & that making code branchless will improve the code faster.

I am trying to understand why the patch in [1] which made the following change, made the code 1.5x faster? (vs. eg 1.1x faster)

[1] https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/107894/files

(The PR's author got 1.5x faster on Zen 3, I got slightly more speed-up on Zen 2 (Ryzen 3900x))

```
- if child + 1 < v.len() && is_less(&v[child], &v[child + 1]) {
-     child += 1;
+ if child + 1 < v.len() {
+     child += is_less(&v[child], &v[child + 1]) as usize;
}
```

Some notes:

- I looked at the assembly code, and the `child += 1` inside the `if` is translated to a simple move between registers. The compiler generated assembly code maintains both child & child+1 in 2 registers. So no memory accesses are happening inside the `if` block.
- PR's author (and I) used an array with 10k elements, which fits in my CPU's L1 cache.

My current understanding of such drastic speed-up is:

1. I profiled the code with AMD uProf:

   1. When running the branchless version, CPI is about 0.45. When running the with branched versioned CPI is about 0.9.
   2. In the branchless version, misprediction ratio is 0.5%. In branched version it is about 10% (for all branches, not just the one we optimized. But other branches are very easy to predict).
2. In the assembly code the whole loop is 24 instructions. So with CPI=0.45, it should take about 11-12 cycles with perfect predictions.
3. Given 1.1, and given that we have many branches, and that for most of them cpu does near perfect prediction, I guess the branch we are optimizing had about 25%-30% (or maybe more) misprediction rate.
4. According to Andrew Fog's guide [2], Zen 3's misprediction penalty is 18 cycles. So with 30% misprediction, this adds about 6 cycles to each loop, which makes the loop 33% (=6 / (12+6)) slower.

[2] https://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf

Is my understanding correct? Am I missing something? Are there any other tools which can help me understand the details of what's going on?

Update:

1. I uploaded the assembly code for branchless & unoptimized versions to https://gist.github.com/pykello/aec1f986de596e3a711809e737e58a68
2. And the godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8Tvj6Yjj7

Comment: Could you share the corresponding assembly? For example extract it via [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bTE7zzP7n)

Comment: You cannot just add cycle on modern processors because they execute instructions in parallel. That being said, this should be a reasonable approximation regarding the high misprediction penalty (and the fact that the processor should not execute much instruction during this time). Besides, why `6 / (12+6)` ? Shouldn't it be `(12+6)/12=1.5` times slower? If so, you get the initial timing. Not to mention you said "or maybe more" so it is fine.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, for "slower" I used the same method as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186730/calculate-x-slower-faster, so X can be [0..1] times slower than something else.


Regarding "or maybe more", it's just a guess because uProf gives only mispredictions for the whole execution, not for single branch.

Comment: @Homer512 I uploaded the assembly code I got for branchless & unoptimized versions to https://gist.github.com/pykello/aec1f986de596e3a711809e737e58a68

Comment: @Homer512 and the goldbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8Tvj6Yjj7

Comment: What does the test data look like?  If it's random then you'd expect 50% misprediction, and anything less would be surprising (or maybe a suggestion that the algorithm is doing redundant compares).

Comment: I find relative percentage gain/loss misleading/unintuitive because A being 33% faster than B does not mean that B is 33% slower than A (asymmetric) as pointed out in your provided link. Meanwhile, A being 1.5 time faster than B also means B is 1.5 times slower than A (symmetric). Changing the method to compare the two is even more missleading. Anyway, if my understanding is correct, the "33% slower" of the question is equivalent to "1.5x faster" before. Besides, you can get more information about the missprediction rate using PEBS (ie. precise events).

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, perhaps we could agree on language like "A takes 50% more time"?

Comment: Ryzen 3900X is a Zen 2 CPU. Zen 3 are the 5000 series desktop CPUs.

Comment: @drewtato you are right. Updated. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: BTW: You could move the `if child + 1 < v.len()` out of the loop since it can only be true in the last iteration. `break` when `child + 1 >= v.len()`, then treat the different abort criteria and the last iteration outside the loop